# How to build correct linq to entities query to get data from multiple entities (left outer join analog)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to use WebGrid HtmlHelper to display data from a few entities. The source for WebGrid is prepared by a linq query: `var query = db.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderStatus)`.
I'm able to display aggregated data from two entities and it works fine.

But in another case when I'm trying to do the same but with another set of data I've got the problem I can't solve.

My Controller query:

```
var query = db.SerNum.Include(o => o.Orders).Include(o => o.Item)
```

My View webgrid:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
grid.Column("Item.Name", "Item Name"),
grid.Column("Price", "Price"),
grid.Column("Order.shpOrderID", "Order ID"),
grid.Column("SellDate", "Date")
))
```

When I'm debugging my project I get an error.

> WebGrid can't be displayed - Item.Name and Order.shpOrderID do not exist

That is because not all `SerNum` have a linked record in the Order and Item tables. Can somebody advice me how to solve this?

Comment: You will have to update your LINQ query but the change depends on what you want to achieve. Do you **only** want to show SerNum records which have an entry in the Order and Item tables or do you want to show **all** records as you do now but with the `Item Name` and `Order ID` columns blank?

Comment: I need to display all rows from SerNum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a DTO, a POCO that is not being tracked and has not ties to EF. This DTO object will match the data you need for your grid and will be called something like `ProductGridView`. This will make your queries much more efficent ad every `.Include()` you use in LINQ selects every column of data from that table. Here is a simple example, just keep in mind I don't know what the properties on your entities looks like:

```
puclic class ProductGridView {
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public DateTime SellDate {get; set;}
}
```

You can now change your link query like so:

```
var results = db.SerNum.Include(o => o.Orders).Include(o => o.Item)
              .Select(x => new ProductGridView{
                  ItemName = x.Item.Name,
                  ...Rest Of Mapping...
              }).ToList();
```

You can now return these results to your grid and it should work and will be much more efficient.

Here is some more info on DTO's: http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html

Comment: Thanx a lot, Paul. Your suggestion works! I find it very helpfull when it is needed to deal with data gethered from multiple entities. The one thing I'm worry about is that there should be more simple solution which not increase the complexity of application. For example - when VS automatically builds controller and views for data model containing some linked entities there is no additional structures required to display simple list of rows with values from different entities even with null values.

Comment: There are tools like AutoMapper that make mapping the DTO's simpler, but I agree there is additional complexity to this solution. I generally only do this for complex models or for high traffic sites.